# Error while getting intersection between two series

Tags: python, pandas

From the pandas dataframe, I randomly picked two components using  `df.sample(n)`.

Then I tried `tmp = pd.df[(randomset)&(randomset2)]['ID']`

And got this error `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'list' and 'bool'`

Where am I doing wrong?

What I'm trying to do is 
pick two random row from data that looks something like below

```
Num      ID
A235     [1,3,4,6,8]
A537     [3,5,2,7,8]
...      ...
```

And get the intersection from those two rows ID part and count it

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Can you show us an expected output? In general, intersection can be achieved by using `pd.merge` with `how='inner'`. Is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: Sorry I was going crazy, forgot to write what I'm trying to get.

Comment: Can you try convert `set(randomset) & set(randomset1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intersection can be performed on sets. So, you have to convert your series to set before applying intersection operation.
Does it help??

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['A235',[1,3,4,6,8]],['A537',[3,5,2,7,8]]], columns=['Num','ID'])
randomset1=set(df.loc[0]['ID'])
randomset2=set(df.loc[1]['ID'])
print(randomset1&randomset2)
```

Output:

```
{8, 3}
```

Comment: Huge thanks for the help.
The data has Num part as index so if I create an index and run as you said I think it will work!